# GET/POST запрос С++

Tags: c++, http

Проверил кучу кода GET/POST запросов для С++, и ни один не работал по разным причинам. Будьте так добры скиньте код GET и POST запроса для С++ (только не библиотечного типа boost::asio)

Желательно и на Unix и на Windows

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это, фактически, просьба найти файлы в интернете.

Comment: А чего не библиотечного-то? В стандартной библиотеке подобного нет, т. к. оно там не нужно, а хорошая реализация таких запросов в один ответ вряд ли влезет. Ещё и кроссплатформенное :)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string post = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n";

post+= "blablabla=123\r\n\r\n";//Запрос подставить по вкусу

int bs = 0;

while (bs < post.size())
{
  bs+= send(socket, post.c_str() + bs, post.size() - bs, 0);
  //Добавить обработку ошибок сокета
}
```